# tikz / tikz-timing does not know arrow tip 'Triangle'

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-timing

I'm using tikz-timing to draw timing diagram. It looks really nice, but I want to apply some  optical improvements like changing the 'arrow tip kind'.

So I added `>=Latex[]` to my tikztimingtable environment, but I get a error from pgf:

> Package pgf error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'Latex'.

I also tried other kinds like Triangle.

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}[
  timing/table/header/.style={font=\bf},
  timing/wscale=2,
  timing/nice tabs,
  >=Triangle
]
.......
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

I don't want to change the arrow tip kind in every `\draw` instruction (located in the `\extracode` section). So I'm looking for a general way to override the default arrow tip kind.

Loaded packages:

```
\usepackage{pgf}                        % primitive drawing library
\usepackage{tikz}                       % PGF frontend, drawing macros
\usepackage{tikz-timing}                % spezial TikZ library for waveform/timing diagrams
  \usetikztiminglibrary{advnodes}       %   sublibrary for advanced anchor nodes
  \usetikztiminglibrary{counters}       %   sublibrary for automated content generation
  \usetikztiminglibrary{clockarrows}    %   sublibrary for for arrows on rising/falling edges
  \usetikztiminglibrary{either}         %   sublibrary for new either symbol
  \usetikztiminglibrary{columntype}     %   sublibrary for 
  \usetikztiminglibrary{overlays}       %   sublibrary for overlay generation
  \usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs}       %   sublibrary for better looking timingtables
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `arrows.meta` library; add to the preamble (after `tikz` has been loaded):

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
```